# Is there a robust way to parse the username and domain from a string?

Tags: c#, active-directory, domain-name

I search for a **robust** way to parse a string into username and domain. The following strings are valid (as specified in the [user name formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

- domain\username
- username
- username@domain

Note that my application has to run offline and can't validate against any service.

**Edit:** I'm looking for a class in the .NET Framework that takes my string to construct a user object that I can use to get the domain and username in the same way like `System.Uri` will parse a url for me.

Comment: If your limit is to only handle 3 different versions you can probably handle that with an `If` statement and an `IF Else` statement.

Comment: As for me, just call 3 parsing - with first, third and second ways. What's the problme? Even without regex it might be easy split & check.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work.

```
static string ParseUserName(string logonName)
{
    if (logonName.Contains('\\'))
    {
        var logonNameParts = logonName.Split('\\');
        return logonNameParts[1];
    }

    if (logonName.Contains('@'))
    {
        var logonNameParts = logonName.Split('@');
        return logonNameParts[0];
    }

    return logonName;
}
```

Comment: Why the `Convert.ToString(logonName)`? And I suppose the `'%'` should be `'@'`.

Comment: Updated. The original code I had was using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().

Comment: I know that this will work but I'm searching for a class that does the parsing for me. I have updated my question.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375175(v=vs.85).aspx : the username can contain '@', thus the second split is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You could obviously use a RegEx like

```
([a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+)[\\@]{0,1}([a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+){0,1}
```

<sub>Only a sample RegEx, will not work on Domains with `.com` or similar endings.</sub>

to get the username and a domain, if one exists. I personally find functions with regular expression hard to support and manage, because of their cryptic notation. If you are limited to 3 notations, I'd say you should implement a function that parses every one of the three notations.